# Retrieving multiple rows from plist

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, plist

I have some code data which is in my plist. I am trying to read that in using Xcode. Basically I want to retrieve multiple rows which satisfy a given condition

I am able to retrieve only 1 row using the following code: but I am not able retrieve more than 1 row. For example I have the following rows

Lodging col1 col2 col3
1.       a.    b.  c
1.       d.    e.  f

`print(getDateForDate(date: "1"))`

```
func getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: String) -> (Array<Dictionary<String,String>>)
        {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "plist")
        var arr : NSArray?
        arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
        return(arr as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>>)!
    }
    func getDateForDate(date: String) -> (Array<[String:String]>)
    {
        let array = getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: "file")
        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Lodging = %@", date)
        return [array.filter{namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}[0]]
    }
```

The above code is able to retrieve row 1 but not row 2. I want to extract all rows which match the condition. Not just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are discouraged from reading plists with the `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` API. Use `PropertyListSerialization` or better deserialize the property list into structs with the `Codable` protocol.

```
func getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: String) -> [[String:String]]
{
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    return try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:String]]
}
```

Your predicate filters the array and returns the first object `[0]`, change the line to

```
return array.filter{namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}
```

The `NSPredicate` in redundant, in Swift you can filter directly. And the parentheses around the return type are redundant, too

```
func getDateForDate(date: String) -> [[String:String]]
{
    let array = getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: "file")
    return array.filter{ $0["Lodging"]! == date }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That helped. Below is the code:

```
return array.filter{namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}
```

I have an array of dictionaries returned which looks like this.

```
[["a":"1","b":"2","c":3],["a":"3","b":"4","c":5]]
```

from this I need to retrieve data for whatever is defined under key "a". How do I go about this?

thanks!

Comment: Once again, the `NSPredicate` is redundant.

Comment: Value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'Lodging' I am getting this error when I use return array.filter{ $0.Lodging == date }